# Splitting non-unique values to unique values in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a problem in that my data (CSV file) are repeating values. But the sequential values are important to each other not to the other. I need to group the rows by the similar values in col a but for values that are only near each other.
 IE for (2,1) =[[0.5, 1.5], [1.2, 2.3], (2,2) = [[1.3, 0.5], [2.5, 1.5]] and so on.

```
     col a          posX           pos y
  0  1               0.5             1.5
  1  1               1.2             2.3
  2  2               1.3             0.5
  3  2               2.5             1.5
  4  3               0.7             0.7
  5  3               1.6             4.0
  6  3               2.1             5.1
  7  1               1.2             2.4
  8  1               1.5             2.5
  9  1               1.6             2.6
  10 2               2.0             1.5
```

Therefore (2,1) != (3,1) they contain possibly different length or different value

my data is big, 25000 lines
therefore I cant be sure that
(2,1) will not occur more than once so I cant use length as the unique value key

I'm struggling  to combine these data without combining all these values because when you use

```
df.groupby['col a']
```

it throws all the 1s together.

thank you

edited to clarify the expected outcome and gave more information

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: The expected outcome is to combine the col A row that is near each other but but not combining it with the other rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to figure out this problem. I am more used to Java in university so it took a while of digging to figure out the problem

creating an empty `np.Array` was difficult. there was a need to know the exact size of the array you are trying to initialise. I did this because I thought the best way to prepopulate this empty Array row by row ie `[[x1,y1], [x2,y2]...]`

I grouped the values I need to use `series = df.groupby(['t', 'col a'])` t being a value to know when `col a` resets

giving me a Series of length number `col a` reseted with a unique key of `(t1, 1), (t2, 1)` each contained a `pd.Dataframe` in each row.

upacked the grouped series into a list and  looped the list

```
unpacked = [x for x in series]
vec_list = list()             # empty list to store the array
for v in unpacked:
    df = v[1]                 # v[0] is the key and v[1] is the dataframe of the grouped value
    x = df.values             # turns the entire df into np.array! 
    vec_list.append(x)
```

`vec_list` will contain the list of grouped np.Array

Answer (score 0):

I believe need helper `Series`:

```
g = df['col a'].ne(df['col a'].shift()).cumsum()
df.groupby(g)
```

Comment: Sorry this did not help. I have updated the question if it helps